# Accessing each button's properties after they are dynamically generated in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, minesweeper

I have used the following code to generate buttons dynamically. I want to know how to code in such a way that if i click one button, there should be some change done to some other button in the same form. Since all the buttons are generated in the loop, i do not know how to call one button elsewhere in the code.

```
   Private Sub random2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)         Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 16
        Dim btn As New Button
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ClickMe
        btn.Width = 23
        btn.Height = 23
        btn.Text = ""
        btn.Tag = i
        btn.Name = i
        btn.Name = "Button" & i
        flp.Controls.Add(btn)   'flp stand for flow layout panel

    Next
End Sub
Private Sub ClickMe(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button
    btn = CType(Sender, Button)
   dim str as string = btn.tag
   MsgBox(str)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You have added all your dynamically created buttons to the FlowLayoutPanel control collection.
You will find them there with syntax like this

```
Dim btn As Button = TryCast(flp.Controls("name"), Button)
if btn IsNot Nothing then
    btn.Caption = "New Text"
    ....
End If
```

Or if you want a button at a specific index

```
Dim btn As Button = TryCast(flp.Controls(index), Button)
```

Comment: You've got half your c# hat on.  VB.Net uses parentheses, not brackets: `flp.Controls("name")`.